# What Features are Missing in the PhraseExpress Text Expander after the Trial Period Ends?

Tags: license, phraseexpress

What features or capabilities will be locked, gone or will be missing in PhraseExpress (text expander software) after the 30-day trial period has elapsed?

Comment: Why don't your ask them?

Comment: They're not replying, so I just want to ask anybody who had already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no features will be removed as long as you do not use the program commercially. Using it commercially means receiving money for what you do with the program.

This means basically that doodling around for fun, unpaid studies and unpaid charity work are ok.

There is actually a link on their website that explains all of that: 
http://www.phraseexpress.com/freeware.htm

FYI, here is what it says on their website:
[image: What is free in the trial version of PhraseExpress]

If you want a free solution that you are allowed to use commercially, check out AutoHotkey (http://www.autohotkey.com/).

Comment: Hi, I've always heard about this AuthoHotKey, is it really the best among the others on that field? What are some other alternatives which do not require programming skills? I look into AutoHotKey last time but I didnt pursue, because it seems like it is not for people who dont know how to code, is it? Tnx

Comment: If you want a free alternative, check out Texter which is AutoHotkey based but has an interface: http://lifehacker.com/238306/lifehacker-code-texter-windows

Comment: Ive just checked Texter, the last updated version is too long ago, Nov. of 2007. Any other good alternatives? Also, is AutoHotKey really the best? All people suggested it most of the time?

Comment: Texter will still work. I don't know what best means to you, but AutoHotkey certainly can do a lot of things that PhraseExpress can't. If you don't mind a bit of learning, AutoHotkey is the way to go as far as free apps go. To get started with PhraseExpress like replacements, read here: http://ahkscript.org/docs/Hotstrings.htm

Comment: Hi from the PhraseExpress makers! We just would like to note, that PhraseExpress has NO "algorithms looking for commercial phrases".

Comment: @PhraseExpress Thanks for the info. Didn't know that you removed the feature.